# Jump Command and compare debug

Tags: assembly

i'm trying to understand some jump commands

edx has -126 and eax has +127

```
cmp edx, eax
ja short <offset>
```

it states the jump is taken, now i understand that its based off of flags being set, what i dont get is how does the math make sense, example if we had a JZ command and result was equal then obviously jump would be taken. from what i understand cmp command subtracts destination from source, in this case it would be -126 added with 127, result is 1, i'm just not getting what MATH result triggers the flag? is all i want to know

Comment: `127 - (-126) == 253`, not `1`... Also, if I remember correctly, `ja` looks at the (Z)ero flag and the (S)ign flag, and takes the jump if neither are set. In other words, if the result of the subtraction was positive and non-zero.

Comment: The code looks like it's in Intel syntax, so it would be `-126 - 127` (which makes more sense when written as `0xFFFFFF82 - 0x7F`)

Answer (score 2):

`ja` means Jump if *unsigned* Above (`CF=0` and `ZF=0`). The corresponding instruction for signed values is `jg`.

The 32-bit value -126 is 0xFFFFFF82, which obviously is greater than 127 (0x7F) when viewed as an unsigned value.

Comment: o i see the FFFFFFF was what i was missing, got ya, i thought it was a negative vs positive thing, but wait what about the cmp operation, doesn't it subtract destination from source? or no? just compares numbers, and while were at it, i've seen an operation where it tests EDI, EDI   and then has a JL, which takes a jump?

Comment: @davidwabb `test edi, edi \ jl somewhere` tests the sign of `edi`. `jl` jumps if `SF xor OF`. `test` sets SF to the sign of the result, and sets OF to zero. So it'll jump if `edi` is negative.